# Write to compiled sass to parent directory of file

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Say I have the file structure:

```
styles
    truly
        very
            deep
                afile.sass
```

And the desired output is

```
styles
    truly
        very
            afile.css
            deep
                afile.sass
```

---

### What I've tried so far:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./truly/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('truly'));
});
```

Almost, but compiles to the same directory.

The following are the `gulp.dest()` parameters I've tried:

`..`

Outputs nothing, probably understanding outside of directory root.

`.`

Replicates the structure from `very` onwards from the root.

`truly/..`

Also replicates outside, I've tried many others with no success either.

Comment: How about `../`? May have the same behavior as `..` but I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems you can also pass `gulp.dest()` a function that returns the path to write to. So you can try some custom logic that decides what the output path will be. https://gulpjs.org/API.html#path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer at [modify parent directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927983/gulp-compile-sass-by-folder-and-modify-parent-directories) a very similar question.

So without testing:

```
const flatten = require('gulp-flatten');    

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('truly/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))

    // will strip off the last directory, 'deep' in your case
    .pipe(flatten({ subPath: [0, -1] }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('truly'));
});
```